# Error: Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key from Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to create an External table in Azure Databricks using Spark SQL e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists newTableTest (country STRING, continent STRING) USING delta LOCATION 'abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/test/newTableTest'
```

This call fails with

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o341.sql.
: Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.SimpleKeyProvider.getStorageAccountKey(SimpleKeyProvider.java:51)
    at shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AbfsConfiguration.getStorageAccountKey(AbfsConfiguration.java:655)
...
```

Note that the folder `test` is not an empty folder. However when try this

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists newTableTest (country STRING, continent STRING) USING delta LOCATION 'abfss://<container>@<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net/test'
```

I get the error -

```
Cannot create table ('`spark_catalog`.`default`.`newTableTest`'). The associated location ('abfss://[REDACTED]fs@[REDACTED]storage.dfs.core.windows.net/test') is not empty but it's not a Delta table
...
```

I have set-up the Service Principal and am using this in the Spark session, like this -

```
service_credential = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="azure_delta_lake_access_scope",key="BlobStoreAccessKey")

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "<some_guid>")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", service_credential)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<storage_account>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<some_guid>/oauth2/token")
```

Interestingly when I do a SELECT from another delta table that is stored in the same ALDS Container, in the same notebook, it works (and correctly returns the values).

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

> Failure to initialize configurationInvalid configuration value
> detected for fs.azure.account.key

The above error mainly happens because no proper access to service principle with Azure storage account.

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the similar error**.

[image]

**To resolve the above error. Please follow this approach:**

Go to your Azure storage account -> click on Containers and select Manage ACL

[image]

Inside Manage ACL Add Service principle and Give access permissions to your storage account.

[image]

Now, you can check the Azure Databricks connected to Azure Data Lake Gen2 with Service principle.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "4853499b-92ae-4839-8ec2-xxxxxxx")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "a4D8Q~cFC1rL9mef6Pdcfk2Aiuxxxxxxxxxxx")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41afxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token")
```

**Sample code:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTableTest
USING delta
LOCATION 'abfss://pool@vamblob.dfs.core.windows.net/example'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion ! However after doing this I still get the error. I also tried setting the Storage Account Key as a part of the spark conf, that didnt work as well. Interestingly when do a SELECT on another delta folder that works, as well as when I do `dbutils.dbutils.fs.ls("some_folder_in_the_storage_container")` it works. Only the CREATE TABLE seems to fail.

Comment: Interestingly the CREATE TABLE seems to create a folder in the storage container which is left dangling, the table itself doesnt get created. (i.e. DESCRIBE TABLE statement gives an error to the effect that table or view not found.

Comment: hi @mithrandir, can you provide error response or error Trase.